# SQL server query to select column associated to a unique value in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Pardon the title but I have a table `TRANSACTIONS(ID,AMOUNT,ITEM_NUMBER`)` with 10 million rows. There are no primary or unique constraints. I want to retun all ID which have a single unique ITEM_NUMBER. Here is sample data to explain what I want to return -

```
1,200,30
2,250,30
2,200,40
3,300,40
3,400,40
4,100,35
4,150,30
1,230,40
```

In above case, I want to return ID 3 since it is associated to only one ITEM_NUMBER.

Comment: holy slow queries...a 10 million row heap? You need a clustered index on that immediately if not sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, AMOUNT, ITEM_NUMBER
FROM TRANSACTIONS T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM TRANSACTIONS 
        WHERE ID = T.ID 
        GROUP BY ID 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM_NUMBER) = 1)
```

Obviously, an index like `NONCLUSTERED (ID) INCLUDE (ITEM_NUMBER)` will help a ton.